# CSS max-width property does not render correctly

Tags: html, css

I have two `<div>`s with `max-width` set to `100px;` Inside first `<div>`, I have a short para with small words. In the second <`div>` I have long words than `100px;` Then the `<div>` goes over the limit. Are there any specific properties to fix this?
Thanks In Advance.

CSS code:

```
#para{
max-width: 100px;
text-align:justify; 
text-justify:inter-word;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<body>
<div id='para'>This para div works fine with max- width property when short words are used</div>
<br/>
<div id='para'>But when long words are used, Like thiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiis It does not render correctly</div>
</body>
```

JSFIddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ShamalSandeep/D2YdA/

Comment: You can use `overflow: auto;' if you want scroll bar OR `overflow: hidden;` if you want to hide the extra letters.

Comment: It's unrelated, but you should not have two identical `id`s on the page. `id`'s are unique.  If you need identical styling for several elements, use `class`

Answer (score 2):

You can add [`word-break:break-all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) to your CSS, this will break every word that ends up at the edge of your element. Or use [`word-wrap: break-word`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) to only break long words.

```
#para{
    max-width: 100px;
    text-align:justify; 
    text-justify:inter-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    /*Or word-wrap: break-word;*/
}
```

**[Demo with `word-break`](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/D2YdA/1/)**

**[Demo with `word-wrap`](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/D2YdA/4/)**

Comment: @ShamalSandeep Glad to help. If your issue has been solved please consider marking this answer as accepted by clicking the green check mark next to it.